# Laravel Avatar Image Not Displaying

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an issue with my Laravel project. I am using Laravel 5.2 on both my local machine (xampp) and my production server Linux Centos / Apache.

On my local machine, the user can upload his/her avatar to my avatar folder under `public/img/avatar` and the image is uploaded and displayed well but when I try the same codes on my production server it doesn't work. What happens on the production server is the image gets uploaded to the `/img/avatar` folder but isn't displayed on the browser. When I debug it shows resource failed to load and can't be found. When I open the image's path in browser's url it gives me a

> **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be
>   found....NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

error even though the image is indeed in the folder.

Some have suggested to have a look at the permissions of my `img/avatar` folder, which is set to 0755 and owned by root.

Here is my code for avatar

```
<?php $avatar = Auth::user()->profile ? Auth::user()->profile->company_logo : 'default.jpg'; ?>

<img src="{{ asset('/img/avatar/' . $avatar) }}"  class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
```

The above works fine on local server xampp but doesn't work on production server. But if for testing purposes I use another image under `/img` folder it works fine on both my local server (xampp) and the prod server (Apache/Centos).

Any idea/suggestion how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you also copy the images to your production server?

Comment: Try using the storage facade {{ Storage::disk('local')->url('file.txt')}}

Comment: Have you verified that the images are stored to disk? It might be better storing the images in the storage folder, check storage_path(), to avoid having to change file system rights on production

Comment: Why are you storing to two different folders? Have you somehow linked `/img/avatar` to your `public` folder in production?

Comment: Hi Jerodev, yes the image are also copied to the server. In my prod server the image exists in the /img/avatar folder but can't just get displayed on the browser

Comment: @kerbholz I am not storying to different folders. There are many folders under /img/ but for avatar images they go to the avatar folder. I use git so my local codes are an exact copy of my production codes. There is a folder /img/avatar in my production server which contains images

Comment: Ok, just thought because you were mentioning `public/img/avatar`, `/img/avatar` and `img/avatar`.

Comment: @kerbholz I see. What is also strange is if I copy an image path url ( e.g http://example.com/img/avatar/image.jpg) in my browser it doesn't show the image while the same test on my xampp works.

Comment: Hm, not sure if `root` is the correct owner for that folder (shouldn't it be `www-data` or something else, don't know about Centos). Also check the permissions and ownership of the image files inside that folder.

Comment: @kerbholz I tried the following `chown -R apache:apache public/img/avatar` and change the permission to apache but nothing still. Also the images in public/img/avatar are owned by apache and permission is set 0644.

Comment: Firstly please go to  the env file and then write debug=true and then find the actual error  ..............and  i think root can not defined